# How can I create mobile automation app testing with BrowserStack Appium with Python?

Tags: python, appium, browserstack, python-appium

I want to create automated tests for Mobile Apps for IOS, (better if both IOS and Android). Until now I've just ran the sample test of this site https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/appium-python. The problem is: I don't know how to create the same kind of tests but for my applications. I have to use BrowserStack and Python, but I don't know how.

Is there some kind of tutorial anywhere on how to create custom tests? Somewhere else it explains what can I do with appium in python and how to do it?

Preferable I would want to create and make the tests with scripts only with out the use of any IDE, but I don't know if there is a best way to do it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Appium Desktop to review the Native App elements and create valid locators for the elements on your application. Please review the documentation [here](https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/appium/appium-desktop).

By locating the elements for the test application successfully you should be able to write the corresponding [Appium commands](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-element/) in your test script.

Comment: @Ozone13 Thank you for your help! If you don't mind can I ask you something else? Do you know if I can start my test on a specific step of the app?

For example, if my app first requires you to scan a QR code to access, can I skip that step and automatically continue with the rest? Because when I get to the part of the process that requires the scan it can't continue because the platform cannot simulate the action of scanning a QR.